# Query Parameter not set in route navigate after i add preserve

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 8, I want to add some bunch of query parameters in order module
in order list component i have search by order number so i need to make query param for the searched result after i go to order details
my order page link : http://127.0.0.1:4200/mall/order
so i go from order page to details page : http://127.0.0.1:4200/mall/order/details/id
i make this code for navigating

```
    this.router.navigate([`${RouteStrings.staff.lookups.details}`, id], {
      queryParams: {
        'search': this.queryParams.search,
      },
      queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'
    })
```

```
Routing Module : 
      {
        path: RouteStrings.mall.orderList,
        component: OrderListComponent
      },
      {
        path: `${RouteStrings.mall.orderList}/${RouteStrings.staff.lookups.details}/:id`,
        component: OrderDetailComponent
      },
```

so when i remove the preserve it work when i go to details page but when i back it disappeared so i need preserve

Any ideas how to get query parameters work?

Comment: just use `queryParamsHandling: "merge"`

Comment: @Andrei i tried merge but not work

Comment: @Andrei any help ?